# Sitemap.xml - Google not indexing

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I have created a sitemap for my site and it complies with the protocol set by http://www.sitemaps.org/

Google has been told about this sitemap via webmaster tools. It has tracked all the urls within the sitemap (500+ urls) but has only indexed 1 of them. The last time google downloaded the sitemap was on the 21st of Oct 2009.

When I do a google search for site:url it picks up 2500+ results.
Google says it can crawl the site.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why only 1 url is actually indexed?

Cheers,
James

Comment: Google crawls every so often. Perhaps it just hasn't been long enough?

Comment: Google has been crawling for a few months now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure Google hasn't been forbidden from those pages using `robots.txt`, etc. Also make sure those URLs are *correct*. :)

Second, Google doesn't just take your sitemap at face value. It uses other factors, such as inbound links, etc, to determine whether it *wants* to crawl all of the pages in your sitemap. The sitemap then serves mostly as a hint more than anything else (it helps Google know when pages are updated more quickly, for example). Get high-quality, relevant, useful links (inbound and outbound) and your site should start getting indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Your two statements seem to contradict one another.

> but has only indexed 1 of them.

and

> When I do a google search for site:url it picks up 2500+ results

bdonlan is correct in their logic (robot.txt and Google's lack of trust for sitemaps) but I think the issue is what you "think" is true about your site.

That is, Google Webmaster Tools says you only have 1 page indexed but site:yoursite.com shows 2.5k.

Google Webmaster Tools aren't very accurate. They are nice but they are buggy and MIGHT help you learn about issues about your site. Trust the site: command. Your in Google's index if you search site:yoursite.com and you see more than 1 result.

I'd trust site:yoursite.com. You have 2.5k pages in Google, indexed and search-able.

So, now optimize those pages and see the traffic flow. :D

Sidenote: Google can crawl any site, flash, javascript, etc.